# Issues reading from an I2C device

Tags: arduino, battery-charging, i2c

I'm testing out the [BQ25887](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25887.pdf) 2 cell balance charging IC, and I'm trying to read the data from the I2C interface. But I'm not getting any results. I am unable to see any values from the serial monitor on the Arduino IDE. To read the data, in my test setup, I have my Arduino Nano attached to my computer with the SDA and SDL lines plugged into Arduino header. The IC and 5V pull-up voltage is being powered by an external voltage source (in this case a battery pack,) which is outputting 5V.

I tried using the 5V from the Arduino Nano to pull-up the I2C lines, but the LEDs on my PCB were oscillating, so I decided not to. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

**Schematic**

[image]

**Test Setup**

[image]

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  // start serial for output

  Wire.begin();        // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0x0D);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0x6B, 1);    // request 6 bytes from slave device #8

  while (Wire.available()) { // slave may send less than requested
    int c = Wire.read(); // receive a byte as character
    Serial.println(c);         // print the character
  }

  delay(500);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

Comment: Are you sharing a ground with the device and the Arduino?

Comment: Okay, so the Arduino and PCB share the same GND, so I'm able to use the 5V on the arduino. But still no luck reading the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looking at the picture, it looks like there is no GND connection between the two boards. You *could* have a valid GND Connection if the USB cords are on the same bus. Anyways, a dedicated GND connection would do good.
2. Try to pull up SDA and SCL to Vin
3. Try using the example from Arduino:

```
    #include
```

`void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();        // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
  Serial.begin(9600);  // start Serial for output
}

void loop()
{
  Wire.requestFrom(2, 6);    // request 6 bytes from slave device #2

  while(Wire.available())    // slave may send less than requested
  { 
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive a byte as character
    Serial.print(c);         // print the character
  }

  delay(500);
}`

Source: [Here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterReader)

Comment: My code is the sample code given, but modified to work with this IC. I've gotten it to work with an IC similar to this one (BQ24193).

Comment: @Jay Are you using the correct address? The address Given in the DS is 0x6A. In the orriginal example, the R/W bit is not toggled.

Comment: @T Andersen Ah man, you're right. Looking at section 8.3.11.5, I thought it was 0x6B. I'll be sure to check the datasheet more thoroughly next time. Thanks for the help!